# Help on a demonstration about properties of helices

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation

In an exercise of Do Carmo's *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces* (section 1-5, 17a), we're asked to show a curve $\alpha$ is a helix iff $\frac{k}{\tau}$ is constant, for nonzero $\tau$. Do Carmo basicly uses the fact that the tangent vector of a helix has a fixed angle with some vector $a$, and by differentiating that condition arrives at the desired condition, like so:

> $t \cdot a=\cos{\theta} \implies n\cdot a=0$
> $a=\cos{\theta}t+\sin{\theta}b\implies (k\cos{\theta}+\tau\sin{\theta})n=0 \implies \\
> \frac{k}{\tau}=-\tan{\theta}$

He then says that for the reverse condition, starting with $\frac{k}{\tau}=$const. and defining that constant to be the symmetric of the tangent of some angle, we can retrace the steps of the first argument. But I don't see how this is the case, because even if I have that $k\cos{\theta}+\tau\sin{\theta}=0$ how can I associate that with a certain vector without loss of generality? In other words this bugs me because it seems as if I could just as well say that this is the norm of a vector congruent with the tangent, or the binormal, which would lead to different results, right? Insight is appreciated

Comment: From the forward proof you’ve done, conjecture what $a$ and $\theta$ should be and show the resulting vector $a$ is in fact constant.

Comment: @TedShifrin  $a$ is a constant unit vector of which direction the tangent makes a constant angle $\theta$ with.

Comment: I know that, but you need the candidate for it, going backwards. What combination of $n$ and $b$ might work?

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't know how to answer that question without feeling I'm already reaching for what I know from the forward proof. I know $a$ to be in the tangent-binormal plane, but starting from $\frac{k}{\tau}$ being constant I don't know how to obtain that information (without reffering to the fact that $a\cdot t$ is constant).

Comment: Sorry. I typed $n$ instead of $t$. You have the candidate vector in your proof. What should the constant $\theta$ be? What constant is sitting in the question?